# What's the proper use of CFNotificationCenter Miscellaneous Callbacks?

Tags: ios, swift

As of [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFNotificationCallback) it's signature and details are as follows:

CFNotificationCallback

Callback function invoked for each observer of a notification when the notification is posted.

Declaration

`typealias CFNotificationCallback = CFunctionPointer<((CFNotificationCenter!, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, CFString!, UnsafePointer<Void>, CFDictionary!) -> Void)>`

Import Statement

`import CoreFoundation`

But I have failed in figuring out how to use it from swift, those pointers seems odd to me.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as your question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493478/how-to-get-notified-of-unlock-device-event-entirely-in-swift Do not just walk away from a question and ask it again in a new form; if the old question has problems, edit the old question instead.

Comment: @matt no, it is not the same question. The other one is trying to find a workaround of an specific problem, this one is to obtain hints and directions of how to use this specific Miscellaneous callback

Comment: Nevertheless, I _have_ correctly answered _this_ question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a CFNotificationCallback in Swift. It is a pointer to a C function. You cannot make a C function or a pointer to a C function in Swift.

Comment: You can, however, make the C function and the pointer in Objective-C and then Swift can obtain the pointer from your Objective-C code. For an example, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_c_functions